# Distinguish functions with lambda argument by lambda's return type?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function `timeout(...)` (extension function that returns `this`) which accepts an argument that is either `String`, `Date` or `Long`. What I am trying to do is to make it accept any lambda that also returns one of these three types.

Kotlin finds the below functions ambiguous and can't decide which one to call when I type, for example, `timeout { "something" }`.

```
@JvmName("timeoutString")
fun <CR: CachableResponse> CR.timeout(timeLambda: CR.()->String): CR = timeout(timeLambda())

@JvmName("timeoutLong")
fun <CR: CachableResponse> CR.timeout(timeLambda: CR.()->Long): CR = timeout(timeLambda())

@JvmName("timeoutDate")
fun <CR: CachableResponse> CR.timeout(timeLambda: CR.()->Date): CR = timeout(timeLambda())
```

The error I'm getting is `Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference`.

Of course one way to work around this, is to have one function instead of three like this:

```
fun <CR: CachableResponse, Type> CR.timeout(timeLambda: CR.()->Type): CR =
        timeLambda().let { when (it) {
            is String -> timeout(it)
            is Date -> timeout(it)
            is Long -> timeout(it)
            else -> this
        } }
```

In this case, though, the developer won't have any clue what its lambda will have to return without reading the description or checking the source code.

Is there any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you solution is rather elegant.
I would only suggest to inline `CR` generic parameter and capture `when` subject in a variable:

```
fun <Type> CachableResponse.timeout(timeLambda: CachableResponse.() -> Type) =
    when (val it = timeLambda()) {
        is String -> timeout(it)
        is Date -> timeout(it)
        is Long -> timeout(it)
        else -> this
    }
```

> In this case, though, the developer won't have any clue what its lambda will have to return without reading the description or checking the source code.

[IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) comes to the rescue:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! As for the latter one, what I meant was if there's a way to specify which types are accept (disallow any type that's not String, Date or Long). Is there way to do that (without using an absurd interface that will make no sense)?

Comment: You may do something like:
`@JvmName("timeoutString")
@Suppress("FINAL_UPPER_BOUND")
fun <T : String> CachableResponse.timeout(timeLambda: CachableResponse.() -> T): CachableResponse = timeout(timeLambda())

@JvmName("timeoutLong")
@Suppress("FINAL_UPPER_BOUND")
fun <T : Long> CachableResponse.timeout(timeLambda: CachableResponse.() -> T) = timeout(timeLambda())

@JvmName("timeoutDate")
fun <T : Date> CachableResponse.timeout(timeLambda: CachableResponse.() -> T) = timeout(timeLambda())`

but it will require user to manually specify generic type for each call

Comment: You still can't specify the type https://i.imgur.com/OzjvU59.png :\

Comment: Works for me: https://pl.kotl.in/rwmpdfSXO
Maybe there is some [typo](https://imgur.com/EzAZBFm)?

Comment: I'll have to check it again. For sure there's a mistake somewhere since it works for you. Thank you a lot for answering my comments also.

Comment: Turns out I was using 1.3.72 in this project... It works fine in 1.4.10.